# Android - Service doesn't create

Tags: java, android

I have some programm, where I want to save the instance of service and use it in another activities. But service doesn't create.
Just see the code, please.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MainService.get(this);
    }

}
```

MainService.java:

```
public class MainService extends Service {
    public static Object sWait = new Object();
    public static MainService instance;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public static MainService get(Context mContext) {
        if (instance == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainService.class);
            mContext.startService(intent);
        }
        while (true) {
            if (instance != null) {
                Log.v("myLogs", "all is good!");
                break;
            }
            synchronized (sWait) {
                try {
                    sWait.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.v("myLogs", "created!");
        instance = this;
        synchronized (sWait) {
            sWait.notify();
        }
    }

}
```

When I don't use while in MainService.get(), service creates. I added this service to manifest file. I don't know where is there error. I need your help.

Comment: because your `while(true)` *blocks* the `UI thread` from proceeding to create the next task which is to create the service

Comment: I would recommend you get rid of the `Service` entirely, until you know **completely and precisely *why*** you are implementing a `Service`. If, at that point, you still feel that you need the service, just start it and get rid of singleton crap.

Comment: Is any another way to do what I want?

Comment: you need to get it through binding mechanism.

Comment: I guess I still need to learn more about the services. I will read what the other guys have suggested. Thank all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just not the way you should use Service in Android.

What you probably need is to use `bindService()` call from your Activity.
See more about bound service here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

If you need the service to be the **same instance** each time you bind to it, call startService once when your application start.

Example code:

```
public class LocalBinder<T> extends Binder {

    private WeakReference<T> mService;

    public LocalBinder(T service) {
        mService = new WeakReference<T>(service);
    }

    public T getService() {
        return mService.get();
    }

}

public class MyService extends Service {

    private final LocalBinder<MyService> binder;

    public MyService() {
        binder = new LocalBinder<MyService>(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ServiceConnection {

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unbindService(this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MyService serv = ((LocalBinder<MyService>) service).getService();
        // serv is your service instance now
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start your service use (call this from your activity!):

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MainService.class);     
startService(serviceIntent);
```

see docs: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/send-request.html

Comment: It's not this that I need. I want to know why service doesn't start when I add while cycle to MainService.get().

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely not the way you are supposed to use services in android.
I would suggest you revisit [the offical android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). 
To get a quick introduction visit this [tutorial here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm).